# Pressing 'Enter' executes Cancel button instead of Submit

Tags: angularjs

```
<form class="stdform stdform2" name="projectForm" ng-submit="saveProject(project, projectForm)"
      novalidate="novalidate">
    <p>
        <div class="par control-group" ng-class="{'has-error': projectForm.projectName.$invalid && (projectForm.projectName.$dirty || submitted)}">
        <label class="control-label" for="projectname">Name</label>

        <div class="controls">
        <span class="field">
            <input id="projectname" type="text" ng-model="project.name" name="projectName" class="form-control"
                   required/>
            <label ng-show="projectForm.projectName.$error.required && (projectForm.projectName.$dirty || submitted)"
                   class="error" for="projectname">Please type project name</label>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Description</label>
        <span class="field">
            <textarea ng-model="project.description" name="projectDescription"
                      style="resize: vertical; height: 110px;" class="form-control input-default"></textarea>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p class="stdformbutton">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="app.project.list">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{saveMessage}}</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Why after pressing the 'Enter' key on keyboard am I redirected to `app.project.list` instead of having the `saveProject(project, projectForm)` function executed?

Comment: I think enter is tied to the first button. If you swap Cancel and Submit around it will work. But that is a lame workaround.

Comment: @user2847643 You are right - swapping helps. You are right - this is lame. :)

Comment: Ok, another workaround, maybe less lame, is to change the Cancel button into `<a "..." >Cancel</a>.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default [`type` for buttons is `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). You have to explicitly *unset* it to `"button"` to avoid the submit action:

```html
<p class="stdformbutton">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ui-sref="app.project.list">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{saveMessage}}</button>
</p>
```

You can also set the `type="reset"` if you want it to clear out the `input` values.

Comment: I've just discovered it and wanted to write here the not-lame solution. You were quicker. :)

Comment: Thank you! The hiddenness of this was insidious, as I was trying to fix with ng-keyup et al. This was such a simple solution!